# Build failure, cannot refer to a declaration with a variably modified type inside block error in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

This is my code which cause the error mentioned above, I have seen a similar question asked by others, but the only answer do not fully address my question, because I doubt that this question should has some better answers.

```
CGPoint pointArray[lines.count];

[lines enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    NSLog(@"%f", pointArray[idx].y);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by [Cannot refer to declaration with a variably modified type inside block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658656/cannot-refer-to-declaration-with-a-variably-modified-type-inside-block?s=1|248.1567) and its linked duplicate [How to write into an array from a dispatch_apply (GCD) loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603166/how-to-write-into-an-array-from-a-dispatch-apply-gcd-loop), you can't access a C-array inside an Objective-C block.

One solution would be to store your `CGPoint` objects in an `NSArray` using `NSValue`.

```
NSArray *pointArray = @[
    [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)],
    [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(10, 20)]
];
```

Once you have your `pointArray` with your `CGPoint` instances, then your block becomes:

```
[lines enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    NSLog(@"%f", pointArray[idx].CGPointValue.y);
}];
```

Comment: Does my answer solve your question or are you looking for more?